# How to get a count of exact double six repeated in a string (6678766566) in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, match, indexof

I'm unable to build a logic to get a count of double six which present in a string.
For example '6678766566' there are three double sixes present in this string.

Comment: do you want overlaps as well? as in 666 => 2

Comment: @Khanna111 yes !

Comment: Use regex to match //^[6]{2}@ then count the occurrences

Comment: @Khanna111 one more thing to clear that in 6666 it should gives me only 1 double six there is no 6 behind or ahead to the double 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   String str = "6678766566";
   int count = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++){
       if(str.charAt(i)=='6' && str.charAt(i+1)=='6'){
            count++;
            i++;
       }
   }
   System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 3):

There can be many ways to do so. Some of the ways are shown below:

1. Using the RegEx pattern, `6(?=6)` and [Java Regex API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html):

   - **`Stream` version**:

   ```
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           long count66 = Pattern.compile("6(?=6)")
                               .matcher("6678766566")
                               .results()
                               .count();

           System.out.println(count66);
       }
   }
   ```

   - **Non-`Stream` version**:

   ```
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           int count66 = 0;
           Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("6(?=6)").matcher("6678766566");
           while (matcher.find()) {
               count66++;
           }

           System.out.println(count66);
       }
   }
   ```

Note that `(?=(regex))` is used for [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

2. Using [`String#indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,int)):

   ```
   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           int count66 = 0;
           String str = "6678766566";

           for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
               int index = str.indexOf("66", 0);
               if (index != -1) {
                   count66++;
                   str = str.substring(index + 1);
               }
           }

           System.out.println(count66);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) api:

```
String s = "6678766766";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("66");
Matcher m  = p.matcher(s);

int count = 0;
while(m.find()) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Note: to include overlaps use pattern `(6)(?=(6))`. This will give count 2 for `666`.

Comment: don't think this will include overlaps as is being asked.

Comment: For that we use pattern `(6)(?=(6))`.

Answer (score 1):

To make it a little interesting, you could use the RegEx way. Note, we are not doing any **Overlaps**.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Match {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "(66)";
        final String string = "667876656666";
        
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        
        //prints 4
        System.out.println("Number of matches: " + matcher.results().count());

    }
}
```

To include overlaps as well:

```
final String string = "667876656666767666";
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
while (i < string.length() -1) {
    if (string.charAt(i) == '6' && string.charAt(i+1) == '6') {
        count++;
    }
    i++;
}

//  prints 7
System.out.println("Number of matches including overlaps: " + count);
```